# Weird and unpredictable behavior by Views and Images from remote URL?

Tags: image, titanium, scrollview, appcelerator, remote-access

Here is my

**APP.js**

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    navBarHidden : true,
    className : 'window',
    backgroundColor : "#efefef"
});

var header = Ti.UI.createView({
    height : 20,
    width : 303,
    top : 0,
    backgroundColor : "#abc"
});
win.add(header);

var scroll = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    top : 44,
    bottom : 44,
    layout : 'vertical'
});
win.add(scroll);
header.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    fetch_images();
});

win.open();

function fetch_images() {
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function() {
            myjson = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            for ( i = 0; i < myjson.length; i++) {
                Ti.API.debug(i);
                var look = new looks(myjson[i])
                scroll.add(look);
            }
        },
        onerror : function(e) {
            Ti.API.debug("STATUS: " + this.status);
            Ti.API.debug("TEXT:   " + this.responseText);
            Ti.API.debug("ERROR:  " + e.error);
            if (Titanium.Network.online) {
                alert('No reponse from server.');
            } else {
                alert('Please Check your Internet connectivity.');
            }
        },
        timeout : 5000
    });
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://xxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxx.json?api_token=xxxxxxxx');
    xhr.send();
}

function looks(image_details) {
    var look_container = Ti.UI.createView({
        height : 325,
        width : 303,
        top : 10,
        layout : 'horizontal',
        backgroundColor : "#cac"
    });
    var look_image = i.UI.createImageView({
        width : 303,
        top : 0,
        left : 0,
        right : 0,
        image : image_details.image_medium
    });

    look_container.add(look_image);
    return look_container;
}
```

I am about to pull my hairs from my head.
Working with this for around last 4-5 hours.
Acc. to the code Image should be something like this

[image]

But it appears like this.

[image]

Any guess whats wrong !! Any help would be grateful ??

As per the code Image should be aligned to top (0px from top). But Image is always down the line in the view and dont stick to the top... ??

**-------------------------EDIT---------------------------**

I editted my code to check for static JPG images

and its same even for the Images in the resources directory

check this question [developer.appcelerator.com/question](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/141034/how-to-achieve-a-layout-in-a-view-)

**code**

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    navBarHidden : true,
    className : 'window',
    backgroundColor : "#efefef"
});

var my_container = Ti.UI.createView({
    height : 325,
    width : 303,
    top : 30,
    backgroundColor : "#cac",
    layout : "horizontal"
});
var my_image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    width : '100%',
    top : 0,
    left : 0,
    right : 0,
    image : 'hello.jpg'
});

my_container.add(my_image);
win.add(my_container);

my_container.addEventListener('click', function() {
    my_image.top = my_image.top - 25;
})

win.addEventListener('click', function() {
    my_image.top = my_image.top + 5;
})
win.open();
```

and [image url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP6xS.jpg) for the image to be used.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is *not the layout properties*, it is image scaling! Note first that you are passing a larger image than the view, so Titanium does some scaling under the sheets.

So  when you define the width of that `ImageView`, if the image you pass is bigger than the view, Titanium scales it using its own mechanism, which obviously, is not what you want, since it has been causing you to tear your hair out the past few days. I believe they scale images from the bottom up, causing your weird problem.

To fix this, you need to take control of the image scaling from Titanium, and pass a new, resized image

To do this, we need to get the original height and width of the image, to preserve the aspect ratio, then figure out a new size, resize the image, and pass it to the imageView.

To get the height and width of the image you kind of have to hack around a bit, here is how I did it with SDK 2.1.1.GA:

**Get Height and Width of a Blob / Image**

```
// Load the image as a blob to get height information
var imageFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile('hello.png');
var blobOfImage = imageFile.read();

// Put it in a imageView, since It wont let me get height from a blob for some reason
var imageView1 = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    image: blobOfImage,
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
});

// This is the important part, toImage this view and you get the height and width of this image
// For some reason we cant get this from a Blob in SDK 2.1.1.GA
var heightOfImage = imageView1.toImage().height;
var widthOfImage = imageView1.toImage().width;
```

Now we calculate the aspect ratio for the width (screen size for iPhone of 320).

**Aspect Ratio**

```
var aspectRatio =  heightOfImage / widthOfImage;
```

And now we can create the new resized image in the imageview.

**New Image!**

```
var my_container = Ti.UI.createView({
    height : 325,
    width : 303,
    top : 30,
    backgroundColor : "#cac",
    layout : "horizontal"
});
var my_image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    top : 0,
    left : 0,
    right : 0,
    image : blobOfImage.imageAsResized(320, 320*aspectRatio) // Note the resize call to the image blob
});
```

Here is the final output :

[image: Screenshot]

So I guess the lesson is dont trust Titanium to scale your images for you.

Comment: Yes I did and it works, I am using version 2.1.1.GA of Titanium.

Comment: can u add a screenshot over here !!

Comment: I am also using   <sdk-version>2.1.1.GA</sdk-version> and testing on IOS 5.1.

Comment: I can scroll through the pictures normally, theres the screenshot, try clearing out your build folder.

Comment: even in the screenshot if you observe there is a lot of space over guy/ boys image. I want this pink area to be below the the Image and not above. Image should be aligned at top left corner. taking the full width of the container and height (if specified) . in my case 240.

Comment: Your main problem is that your only showing part of the image, crop the image first [(using Titanium Blob utilities, imageAsCropped)](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.Blob)and then layout will be a lot easier to manage and much more straightforward.

Comment: I am not pretty much aware how this Blob thing works or how how to implement this ? Can you suggest me some demo/snippet so that I can get familiar with this. It would be even better if it is linked to my code somehow.

Comment: I'm not going to write your code for you, check the docs I linked too, experiment, fail, come back and post a new question, and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: I have updated the question. As I see now this makes that the issue is with the Images rendering or something like that. Not with fetching image ----->> whether source is remote url or the local url.